# How change class of a math symbol?

Tags: symbols

`\rightarrow` has math symbol class 3, that is, it is a math relation.

How can I define a macro, let's call it `\rightinf`, to get the same right arrow character, but as an ordinary math symbol (like `\infty`, say) rather than as a math relation?

*Reason for the question:* 
I want to use `\rightinf` to designate intervals in an ordered set that are not bounded above, as in `(0, \rightinf)`, instead of `(0, \infty)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
\newcommand{\rightinf}{\mathord{\rightarrow}}
```

or, more concisely,

```
\newcommand{\rightinf}{{\to}}
```

(`\to` is an alias for `\rightarrow`.)

Creating a macro called `\rightinf` in this manner may be unnecessary, though, at least for the use case you laid out: `$(0,\to)$` and `$(0,{\to})$` produce the exact same output.

Here's a full MWE. It illutrates my point about `$(0,\to)$` and `$(0,{\to})$` producing the exact same output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\rightinf}{{\to}}
\begin{document}
$(0,\to)$

$(0,\rightinf)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: But since `\to` is an alias for `\rightarrow` and `\rightarrow` is a math relation (class 3), doesn't the concise definition `\newcommand{\rightinf}{{\to}}` keep `\rightinf` as a math relation? Or does the extra grouping around `\to` in that definition convert it into an ordinary math symbol (class 0)?

Comment: @murray: Indeed, encasing `\to` (or any other math-mode object, really) in curly braces changes its math status to `math-ord`.

Comment: @Mico Could you add an image to understand your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Done! :-)

Comment: Since `\to` is of class 3 (math rel), why does the spacing stay the same for the `\mathord` version (invoked in the form `\mathord{\rightarrow}`) as for the original math rel form?

Comment: @murray - Sorry, noticed your final follow-up question only now. (Just 5 years late...) The answer to your comes down to the fact that spacing rules between adjacent objects with status `mathrel` (such as `\to`) and `mathclose` (such as `)`, respectively, happen to be the same as between adjacent objects of status `mathord` and `mathclose`, resp.

Answer (score 4):

Since `\rightarrow` is a `\mathchardef` token, you can define

```
\mathchardef\rightinf=\numexpr\rightarrow-"3000\relax
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\mathchardef\rightinf=\numexpr\rightarrow-"3000\relax

\begin{document}

$a\rightarrow b$

$a\rightinf b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand,

```
\newcommand{\rightinf}{\mathord\rightarrow}`
```

is simpler.